# Datatype mismatch on Boolean?

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-8

Something strange is happening, I have been seeding my project with some data for over 2 months already and suddenly today I couldn't seed them. So I went over to the test file and it's the same thing.

In migration, the column is

```
$table->boolean('is_visible')->default(true);
```

In factory

```
'is_visible' => true
```

In my test, it throws the query exception when i do

```
EmploymentType::factory()->create();
```

This is the error

```sh
Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  column "is_visible" is of type boolean but expression is of type integer
LINE 1: ...visible", "updated_at", "created_at") values ($1, $2, $3, $4...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. (SQL: insert into "employment_types" ("name", "is_visible", "updated_at", "created_at") values (FULL-TIME, 1, 2021-05-01 01:19:05.980494, 2021-05-01 01:19:05.980494) returning "id")
```

I can see that the values that is inserting is `1` - an integer but previously it was `true`. I have no idea how to fix this as all the other tables that have boolean like this is having the same errors. The only difference I did was upgrade *PHP* `7.4.16` to `7.4.18`

Currently on:

`Database - Postgres 13`

`Laravel Framework 8.34.0`

Update:

Test with `'true'` or `'1'` works but not `true` or `1` - why does this happen? Need some advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same issue with PHP 8.0.5.  Looks like it's a bug in the most recent [release](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=81002).  I saw on the notes for the [original bug fix](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80892) that it will be reverted in the next PHP update.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a bug in the recent version of PHP8 and it appears when you use PostgreSQL.
To all those, who want to use, laravel 8 and php8 on a brand new application and don't want to go back to using an older version of PHP.

Instead of using, `string` version `true` or `1`,
use this

```
DB::raw('true')
```

This will work for any database and it will be the most consistent solution as you're not relying on PHP to do anything.

Make sure to import this at the top

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

**EDIT**
In `PHP 8.0.8` the problem is fixed.